# Facebook API images not downloading

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

First post here,
    i am developing a app to fetch and download facebook images from user's account.
    I have a basic code till now as follows.. 
    Need help as to why only the 1 file keeps downloading alone...in the zip i create
    it is the only image without the ?oh= concatenation, all others with the oh parameter dont get
    downloaded...

```
    <?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $url='https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos/uploaded?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAEGw8R4QOGfN3bfX8qtuZCCy8FX6g5Sil8CKaYlp9x8lZAiNFEGJXhh9MYOWdZAJR1x2M627rc5I3n3AauVe8nJtYBsehjUZAljMLkQMMxP03VVXknZBa81Nk1S23z7SnyTkIlgt2oZC1euoFNCTuGesAap1uQUGZAX7LnILlBwyj3V7IVo9QQCNv66Lv8UcA86wYn9jlJE';

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $a=json_decode($result, true);
    $files = array();
    echo '<div class="col-lg-12">';
    $num= count($a['data']);
    echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive'>";
    for($o=0;$o<$num;$o++)
    {
       $files_to_zip[$o]=$a['data'][$o]['source'];
       if($a['data'][$o]['source']!="")
       {
        echo "<tr><td><img src='".$a['data'][$o]['source']."' id=".$o." width='200' height='200' /></td></tr>";
        array_push($files,$a['data'][$o]['source']);
        //echo $files_to_zip[$o]."<br/><br/><br/><br/>";
       }

    }
    echo '</table></div><br/>';


    ?>
```